# genus of normalization of stable curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a stable curve of genus $g$ over the field $k$, i.e., a $k$-rational point of the Deligne-Mumford stack $M_g$.

What is the genus of the normalization of $X$? Does it depend on the number of singularities of $X$?

Note that the normalization of $X$ is a smooth curve. It is still geometrically connected and it is projective.

Answer (score 3):

The normalization $X'$ of $X$ needs not be conneced, because a stable curve is not necessarily irreducible. So $X'$ is the disjoint union of the normalizations of the irreducible components of $X$. It genus (as sum of genus of its components or its arithmetic genus) can be computed in terms of the arithmetic genus and the number of singular points of $X$. If this is what you are looking for, I will write the formula. In the *irreducible* case:

$$g(X')=p_a(X)- \text{the number of singular points.}$$

Comment: Could you tell me the reference of the proof of your last formula?

Answer (score 2):

The genus is a birational invariant, and a curve is birational to its normalization. For example, see [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152/how-do-you-see-the-genus-of-a-curve-just-looking-at-its-function-field) on MO.

Comment: The geometric genus is indeed a birational invariant. But if one talks about a stable curve of genus $g$, then one normally means the arithmetic genus. Indeed all point on $\overline{M_g}$ all have arithmetic genus $g$, but differing geometric genus.